# Unknown runtime version named 'corretto8' of java. This build image has the following versions: openjdk11, openjdk8

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am trying to build my java project in aws code build. My build is failing with this error message.

> Unknown runtime version named 'corretto8' of java. This build image
>   has the following versions: openjdk11, openjdk8

Build image used: ubuntu,
Runtime used:corretto8

Answer (score 4):

This error is due to, trying to use java runtime corretto8 with ubuntu standard image.

If you are using 'ubuntu standard image' for the AWS CodeBuild instance, then openjdk8 or openjdk11 should be used as java runtime. Below is the  buildspec.yml.

```
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: openjdk8
```

If you are using 'amazon linux image' for the AWS CodeBuild instance, then corretto8 or corretto11 should be used as java runtime. Below is the buildspec.yml.

```
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto8
```

For more checkout
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-runtime-versions.html

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu supports `corretto11` and `corretto8` in its latest version. `Ubuntu standard:2.0` & `Ubuntu standard:3.0` supports `openjdk8` and `openjdk8` only for Java.

So, Make sure you are using `Ubuntu standard:4.0`.

Please see my cloudformation snippet below to see how it is setup in our case.

```
        "Environment": {
            "Type": "LINUX_CONTAINER",
            "ComputeType": "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL",
            "Image": "aws/codebuild/standard:4.0",
            ...
            }
```

Build environment reference: [Ubuntu 18.04 and Amazon Linux 2 platforms runtimes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html)